# PIL is installed but Django ImageField not working

Tags: python, django

```
(env)user@user:~/job/django/webr$ sudo pip install PIL
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): PIL in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL
Cleaning up...
```

but If I run syncdb I have:

> CommandError: One or more models did not validate: content.desing:
>   "img": To use ImageFields, you need to install the Python Imaging
>   Library. Get it at http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ .

I use django 1.5. What is wrong?

```
class Design(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    desc = models.TextField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to="project_images")
```

Comment: Is it possible to post your model or a limited version of it?

Comment: Check that `PYTHONPATH` is the same between the two test environments.

Comment: Is `content.desing` as spelling error or is it the actual error?

Comment: run `python manage.py shell` in your project dir and then see if you can do `import pil`, if not, `import sys`, and `print sys.path`

Comment: maybe you should try PILLOW instead of PIL, PILLOW is user friendly and easy to use

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you have not installed `PIL` for the python running django - I can see you have installed `PIL` somewhere but with the `sudo` command and the fact your're in a `virtualenv` this gets quite confusing without *all* the facts.

First check that you really do have `PIL` installed and which python you're running

```
 $ which python
 /path/to/env/python

 $ pip freeze   # note NO sudo
```

should list `PIL` and

```
 $ python -c "import Image"
```

should not return any error.

Then make sure that the python which calls `django` is the same one as in the above steps

```
 $ python manage.py shell
 >>> import Image
```

If any of these steps causes an error, you are one step closer to tracking this down.